# Why my nsis script can not run command with execWait on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, nsis

I want my nsis script to run the command line which is installed by my previous statements in my script successfully. But it always fails showing

```
C:\mypath\SystemMaitainer.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I put the related code after "install" section as below:

```
Section "install"
// Files copy statements
SectionEnd

Section "command"
    nsExec::ExecToLog 'cmd.exe /c "$INSTDIR\SystemMaitainer.exe" -install'
    Pop $0
    DetailPrint ""
    DetailPrint "       Return value: $0"
    DetailPrint ""
SectionEnd
```

How to fix my problem? Thanks! Why the statement about "nsEXec" always fails, but the command can run successfully in cmd ?

After investigation, my script can work, I should put the execwait command and the copy statements together as below:

```
Section "serverice"
    ClearErrors
    SetOutPath "$SYSDIR"
    file "mycmd.exe"

    ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\mycmd.exe" -option'
SectionEnd
```

But it worked perfectly on Windows 7, but it fails on Windows 10, ExecWait can't run successfully, and without the ret error message, please help me again! I am very appreciate guys who helped me!

Comment: Showing the `File` command would help. Also, is $InstDir inside the Windows directory? Program Files?

Comment: Windows dir, thanks!

Comment: You have not yet added the `File` command to your example. I also want to know what the value of $InstDir is.

Comment: It's $SYSDIR,  "C:\Windows\System32\", is any special protection policy on Windows 10?

Comment: $SysDir is somewhat special but I can't say for sure since you refuse to show the `File` command and the things around it!

Comment: if you really appreciate the help, then upvote and accept answers

Answer (score 2):

That error message is coming from cmd.exe. SystemMaitainer is spelled incorrectly, perhaps that is the problem? Or maybe you disabled WOW64 redirection around the copy command but not the exec command?

You don't have to prefix the command with `cmd /c` if you are not doing stdout redirection.

$SysDir is special because there are two system32 directories on a 64-bit system.

You can access the 64-bit system32 directory in a 32-bit process with `$WinDir\SysNative\` or with the macros in x64.nsh:

```
!include x64.nsh
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
ExecWait '"$SysDir\app.exe"'
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have updated question, I have problem on Win10, any suggestion to fix?

Comment: Yes! That's the key point! I also find it myself! I must put the exec statements between these two X86's macro, Thanks!